# Getting a 404 response back from my local host

Tags: api, localhost, endpoint

I've been given a home assignment for a job interview. For me to get going I need to work with an API end point they've provided me but I can't get it running for some reason. It should be straight forward but I keep getting 404 back.

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "frontend-dev-assignment",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "canned": "0.3.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "3.5.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "canned -p 5000 ./api/"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

In that same directory I have a folder named `api` and in it a file called `_search.get.json`. This is the contents of that file (shortened):

```
[
  {
    "term": "Abyssinian",
    "resultCount": 61
  },
  {
    "term": "Aegean",
    "resultCount": 26
  },
  {
    "term": "American Curl",
    "resultCount": 56
  }
]
```

In the parent folder I ran `npm install` and then `npm start`. I got this line in my CLI:
`starting canned on port 5000 for C:\Users\Yanay\Documents\Coding\Autocomplete\api` (Autocoplete is that parent folder).

But when I try to access `http://localhost:5000/` or `http://localhost:5000//search?q=xxxx` I keep getting a 404 back.
What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Is using canned compulsion , I mean why don`t you just create a server?

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth Well simply put, I'm a junior front end developer! I've worked with some api endpoints in some courses I took but never built a server. Most of my work I've done with firebase.

Comment: You can try this https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html It is very simple instead of trying canned package. This will enhance your nodejs development skills.

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth ok I'll check it out thanks